# Unable to find downloaded video in gallery Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am working on one project which have list of short videos and i want to donwload in external storage. I am using following packages:

1. video_player: ^2.6.1
2. path_provider: ^2.0.15
3. flutter_downloader: ^1.10.2
4. permission_handler: ^10.2.0
5. gallery_saver: ^2.3.2

Successfully video is downloaded in external storage and I am able to play video from notification(from download status). but after once **i opened video i can not seen any where in external storage, unable to find downloaded video.**

As a solution i tried gallery_saver package but it shows msg video file not found.
Please anybody can solve this issue.

Following are my code:

**Added code in Mainifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

 <provider
           android:name="vn.hunghd.flutterdownloader.DownloadedFileProvider"
           android:authorities="${applicationId}.flutter_downloader.provider"
           android:exported="false"
           android:grantUriPermissions="true">
           <meta-data
               android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
               android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
       </provider>
```

**FullCode**

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gallery_saver/gallery_saver.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter_downloader/flutter_downloader.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:flutter_downloader/flutter_downloader.dart';


void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await FlutterDownloader.initialize(debug: true);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(

      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  late VideoPlayerController _controller ;
  late Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;

  Duration _position = Duration.zero;
  Duration _duration = Duration.zero;
  int _progress = 0;

  ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();

  static downloadCallback(id,status,progress){
    SendPort? sendPort = IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName("downloadingVideo");
    sendPort?.send(progress);
  }

  

  @override
  void initState(){
    // TODO: implement initState
    FlutterDownloader.registerCallback(downloadCallback);
    IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(receivePort.sendPort, "downloadingVideo");
    receivePort.listen((message) {
      setState(() {
        _progress = message;
      });
    });



    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network("https://aleyia.tech/Noha_Status/Ramzan_Status/ramzan.mp4")
    ..addListener(() {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {
          _position = _controller.value.position;
          _duration = _controller.value.duration;
        });
      }
    });
    //_controller = VideoPlayerController.asset("assets/ramzan.mp4");
    _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize().then((value) => setState((){}));
    _controller.setVolume(1.0);

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
  }

  String _formatDuration(Duration duration) {
    final HH = (duration.inHours).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    final mm = (duration.inMinutes % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    final ss = (duration.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0');
    return '$mm:$ss';
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Video from url"),),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Center(
            child: _controller.value.isInitialized ?
            AspectRatio(aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
              child: GestureDetector(
                //behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
                onTap: (){
                  setState(() {
                    _controller.value.isPlaying ? _controller.pause() :
                    _controller.play();
                  });

                },
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    VideoPlayer(_controller),
                    _controller.value.isPlaying ? Container():
                    Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        color: Colors.black26,
                        child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow,color: Colors.white,size: 80,)),
                    Positioned(
                      bottom: 0,
                        right: 0,
                        left: 0,
                        child: VideoProgressIndicator(_controller, allowScrubbing: true)),
                    Positioned(
                      bottom: 0,
                      right: 0,
                      child:
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              _formatDuration(_position),
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11,color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                            Text("/",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12,color: Colors.white),),
                            Text(
                              _formatDuration(_duration),
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11,color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),),
                    Positioned(
                      right: 0,
                        top: 0,
                        child: IconButton(onPressed: () {
                          print("download tap");
                          _downloadFile();

                        },
                        icon: Icon(Icons.download, color: Colors.white,),))
                  ],
                ),
              ),) :
                const CircularProgressIndicator()
          ),
          Text("Download percentage   $_progress")
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            if(_controller.value.isPlaying){
              _controller.pause();
            }else{
              _controller.play();
            }
          });
        },
        child: Icon(_controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow_outlined),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _downloadFile() async{
    var url = "https://server/video.mp4";
    final status = await Permission.storage.request();
    if(status.isGranted){
      final baseStorage = await getExternalStorageDirectory();


      final id = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(url: url,
          savedDir: baseStorage!.path,
          fileName: "status_video.mp4",
        openFileFromNotification: true,
        showNotification: true,
        //headers: {"Content-Type": "video/mp4"},
      );
      print('Download started: $id');
      print('File saved at: $baseStorage');

      final file = File('$baseStorage/status_video.mp4');
      final isFileExists = await file.exists();
      if (isFileExists) {
        final result = await GallerySaver.saveVideo(file.path);
        print('Video file saved: $result');
      } else {
        print('Video file not found.');
      }
    } else {
      print('Storage permission not granted.');
    }
  }


}
```